# How do I use gcp package from outside of google datalabs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I created a google compute instance with jupyter and I'd like to use all the nice things datalabs has. Is there a way to get the packages like gcp and the cellmagic like %%sql and %%storage. I found the packages gcloud and google-api-python-client but I don't know if it's the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab will give you Datalab-compatible functionality within Jupyter.

Note, however, that the gcp.* prefix has changed to datalab. I.e. datalab.bigquery, datalab.storage, etc.

Also note that you will need to install the Google Cloud SDK (which has the gcloud command) in your instance.

Comment: Hey Graham. Thank you for creating this, it is a godsend. 

I had to copy the datalab folder to /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ before running
jupyter nbextension install --py datalab.notebook 

then it worked, however, I get strange error

ImportError: No module named '_project'. Error occurs in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/datalab/context/_context.py

Comment: The most obvious explanation for this is that we are not Python 3 compatible yet; only 2.7.

Comment: I'm working on Python 3 compatibility; hopefully by next week.

Comment: Thanks so much for what you've done. Much love for it!

Comment: There is a branch now with Python 3 support. You can get it with 'git clone -b py3 https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab.git', then follow the installation instructions at https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab. Note that you will need node.js and Typescript installed (once you have the former you can install the latter with 'npm install -g typescript').

Comment: Is the Python version needed determined by the Jupyter Python version or the Python version running the base code in the notebook,, I assume the former, eg my Jupyter NB runs from P3 but runs p2 notebooks..so I need the p3 version of this code.