# Accessing Big Query from Cloud DataLab using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I have a Jypyter Notebook accessing Big Query using Pandas as the vehicle:

```
df = pd.io.gbq.read_gbq( query, project_id = 'xxxxxxx-xxxx' )
```

This works fine from my local machine! (great, in fact!)
But when I load the same notebook to Cloud DataLab I get:

```
DistributionNotFound: google-api-python-client
```

Which seems rather disappointing! I believe that the module should be installed with Pandas.. but somehow Google is not including it?
It would be most preferable for a bunch of reasons to not have to change the code from what we develop on our local machines to what is needed in Cloud DataLab, in this case we heavily parameterize the data access...

Ok I ran:

```
!pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Now when I run the notebook I get an auth prompt that I cannot resolve since DataLab is on a remote machine:

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:
 >>> Browser string>>>>
If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter 

 --noauth_local_webserver
```

Don't see an obvious answer to this?

I use the code suggested below by @Anthonios Partheniou from within the same notebook (executing it in a cell block) after updating the google-api-python-client in the notebook
and I got the following traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-038366843e56> in <module>()
  5                            scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
  6                            redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
----> 7 storage = Storage('bigquery_credentials.dat')
  8 authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
  9 print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/file.pyc in __init__(self, filename)
 37 
 38     def __init__(self, filename):
---> 39         super(Storage, self).__init__(lock=threading.Lock())
 40         self._filename = filename
 41 

 TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

He mentions the need to be executing the notebook from the same folder yet the only way that I know of for executing a datalab notebook is via the repo?

While the new module of using the new Jupyter Datalab module is a possible alternative The ability to use the full Pandas BQ interface unchanged on local and DataLab instances would be hugely helpful! So xing my fingers for a solution!

```
pip installed:
GCPDataLab 0.1.0
GCPData 0.1.0
wheel 0.29.0
tensorflow 0.6.0
protobuf 3.0.0a3
oauth2client 1.4.12
futures 3.0.3
pexpect 4.0.1
terminado 0.6
pyasn1 0.1.9
jsonschema 2.5.1
mistune 0.7.2
statsmodels 0.6.1
path.py 8.1.2
ipython 4.1.2
nose 1.3.7
MarkupSafe 0.23
py-dateutil 2.2
pyparsing 2.1.1
pickleshare 0.6
pandas 0.18.0
singledispatch 3.4.0.3
PyYAML 3.11
nbformat 4.0.1
certifi 2016.2.28
notebook 4.0.2
cycler 0.10.0
scipy 0.17.0
ipython-genutils 0.1.0
pyasn1-modules 0.0.8
functools32 3.2.3-2
ipykernel 4.3.1
pandocfilters 1.2.4
decorator 4.0.9
jupyter-core 4.1.0
rsa 3.4.2
mock 1.3.0
httplib2 0.9.2
pytz 2016.3
sympy 0.7.6
numpy 1.11.0
seaborn 0.6.0
pbr 1.8.1
backports.ssl-match-hostname 3.5.0.1
ggplot 0.6.5
simplegeneric 0.8.1
ptyprocess 0.5.1
funcsigs 0.4
scikit-learn 0.16.1
traitlets 4.2.1
jupyter-client 4.2.2
nbconvert 4.1.0
matplotlib 1.5.1
patsy 0.4.1
tornado 4.3
python-dateutil 2.5.2
Jinja2 2.8
backports-abc 0.4
brewer2mpl 1.4.1
Pygments 2.1.3
```

end

Comment: I couldn't produce the exception. Can you please run the following commands and reply with the oauth2client version? Run `import oauth2client` followed by `oauth2client.__version__`

Comment: Also run `import pip` followed by `for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions(): print dist`

Comment: import oauth2client
2
oauth2client.__version__
'1.4.12'

Comment: Pip Installed list above

Comment: I deployed a clean instance of datalab using https://datalab.cloud.google.com/ and the code I provided in my answer worked. One thing I noticed is that in my list of installed python modules I see `google-api-python-client 1.5.1` , but I didn't see `google-api-python-client` in the output that you provided.

Comment: Strange.. I'll try a stop and redeploy in the am, I have not attempted any mods, so not sure how I'm out of synch. Guess maybe just because I have not restarted in a while? Would it (google-api-client be something I need to install on datalab?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114794/discussion-between-anthonios-partheniou-and-dartdog).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google BigQuery authentication in pandas is normally straight forward, except when pandas code is executed on a remote server. For example, running pandas on Datalab in the cloud. In that case, use the following code to create the credentials file that pandas needs to access Google BigQuery in Google Datalab.

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.file import Storage
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id='<Client ID from Google API Console>',
                           client_secret='<Client secret from Google API Console>',
                           scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
                           redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
storage = Storage('bigquery_credentials.dat')
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ')
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
storage.put(credentials)
```

Once you complete the process I don't expect you will see the error (as long as the notebook is in the same folder as the newly created `'bigquery_credentials.dat'` file).

You also need to install the `google-api-python-client` python package as it is [required by pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#optional-dependencies) for Google BigQuery support. You can run either of the following in a notebook to install it.

Either

```
!pip install google-api-python-client --no-deps
!pip install uritemplate --no-deps
!pip install simplejson --no-deps
```

or

```
%%bash
pip install google-api-python-client --no-deps
pip install uritemplate --no-deps
pip install simplejson --no-deps
```

The `--no-deps` option is needed so that you don't accidentally update a python package which is installed in datalab by default (to ensure other parts of datalab don't break).

Note: With pandas 0.19.0 (not released yet), it will be much easier to use pandas in Google Cloud Datalab. See [Pull Request #13608](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/13608)

Note: You also have the option to use the (new) google datalab module inside of jupyter (and that way the code will also work in Google Datalab on the cloud). See the following related stack overflow answer:
[How do I use gcp package from outside of google datalabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337381/how-do-i-use-gcp-package-from-outside-of-google-datalabs)

Comment: Just tried it with no luck, updated post at the bottom with traceback Any help appreciated!

Comment: Closer! I completely restarted the instance and ran the pip installs I then got the prompt to get the verification code but the link gave me a 404 Error: invalid_client

The OAuth client was not found.
Request Details
access_type=offline
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery
response_type=code
redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
client_id=<Client ID from Google API Console>   I have noticed I get some issues on parts of cloud like the repo and BQ and have to use incognito as it won't honor multi users on Chrome? I did try incognito to open this link also but no luck

Comment: Please replace `<Client ID from Google API Console>` and `<Client secret from Google API Console>` with the client Id and secret that you get when you create credentials in the BigQuery management project

Comment: I think it's under the permissions menu after you click on the BigQuery heading in Google Cloud Console

Comment: found it under api's

Comment: Way further 1st it said I needed to create Secret for native app not web app could not find so I selected "other" got a code entered but got this traceback:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.pyc in step2_exchange(self, code, http, device_flow_info)
   2023       else:
   2024         error_msg = 'Invalid response: %s.' % str(resp.status)
-> 2025       raise FlowExchangeError(error_msg)
   2026 
   2027 

FlowExchangeError: invalid_grant

Comment: Yes, I selected `other` as well. Create an OAuth client ID. You'll need to enter both ClientID and secret. I found a good resource here. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project

Comment: Second try the charm! it is working! Thanks so much!! whew need to add the bit about how to do the api key!

Comment: Also rather strange, while it is working I do not see the bigquery_credentials.dat file in any of my visible storage buckets? Any hints?

Comment: The file `bigquery_credentials.dat` should be generated in the same folder as the notebook that created the credentials

Comment: But as I understand the notebook it transitory unless committed to the repo so maybe the storage is not accessible via a user interface? so there is some sort of working file someplace? I see it in the notebook interface. but not in a storage bucket? so could I commit it (a bad idea I'm sure!)

Comment: You can commit the notebook without the client Id and secret. It is quick to generate the bigquery_credentials.dat file once you have the notebook and client Id/secret handy

Comment: My curiosity is tweeked bit more as to the use of the temp (I guess) storage for working transitory (like a report generated out of a NB) files